# Is the value of the determinant of a large matrix the same as the value of the determinant of its chunked matrix?

Tags: determinant, matrix-equations

An $8 \times 8$ matrix $M$ is directly computed by computing its determinant $|M|$, and by dividing it into blocks $ M = \left [ \begin{matrix}
  A & B 
 \\ C & D
\end{matrix} \right ] _{4 \times 4} $,$A, B, C, D$ are the $2 \times 2$ matrix, compute determinant value of $ \left | \begin{matrix}
  A & B 
 \\ C & D
\end{matrix} \right | _{4 \times 4} $, are these two values the same?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Determinant might be what you are looking for.

Comment: "chunked matrices" $\to$ "blocks"

Comment: You might be interested as well by the [Cauchy-Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula)

Comment: Oh, thank you for your replies.